# HighChart find type of series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to find out the type of series through tooltip's formatter function.
I wan't to hide some content based on the series type.

My requirement, the graph is a combination of spline and scatter graph, whenever I hover some scatter graph, I want to hide some content on the tooltip.

```
chart_options.series = [
                 {name: 'Spline Category', data: [1.5,2.5,3.5]},
                 {type: 'scatter', name: 'Scatter category', data: [1,2,3]},
                           ]
```

How can i identify the graph type, `this.point.series.chart.options.chart.type` is giving spline for both graphs !

eg: https://jsfiddle.net/var23rav/aaa6wvye/
I want to hide the yaxis value (8,7,9) while hover on the scatter type graph

Comment: Create a working example (jsfiddle/snippet) with the relevant data and tooltip and explain what to hover and what data should not be in the tooltip. Otherwise it's really hard to help.

Comment: You seem to be asking for the chart type, not the series type - what is `this.series.options.type`? You should only use the chart type for series *without* an explicit one.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe this.series.options.type works.